# how to run a standalone python script via gunicorn/wsgi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

i have a standalone web-based python script, `rpc.py` which is built as a cgi script for direct access through a web server. it is handling all http headers, requests and what have you got. running a web server, with `mod_cgi`, `rpc.py` can be executed as:

`http://127.0.0.1/rpc.py?service_id=atestservice`.

to avoid the cgi approach in production i want to use wsgi. i have no experience with wsgi from before. however, after some research, it seems like the use of [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) with [gunicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunicorn) is a good option. hence, my question: is there a simple way to wrap `rpc.py` inside a wsgi app, and just pass on all request parameters?

pseudocode of wanted result:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
  data = execute_as_web_request(rpc.py, get_parameters)
  return iter([data])
```

what is the best approach in such a situation? is it rewriting `rpc.py` into a wsgi app? or, maybe just run this script via fastcgi?